# Mongo indexing for complex $and and $or query

Tags: mongodb, database-design, mongodb-query, database-performance

I'm trying to various options to optimize my query response. This collection, named nodeData, has 20M records. My queries are hitting the disk instead of index and slows down my server for the rest of the queries.

```
db.nodeData.find({ "$or" : [ { "neid" : "40-cb-28-dd-46-e7-d9-c3"} , { "$and" : [ { "hubId" : "87-0c-4e-a6-ff-39-cc-94"} , { "nodeId" : 1}]}] , "capturedAt" : { "$lte" : new ISODate("2017-11-19T05:17:30.000Z") , "$gt" : new ISODate("2017-11-12T05:17:30.000Z")}}).explain("executionStats")
```

CPU usage shoots upto 90% and my machine is unusable because of this. In this case, I have got an $and and an $or in a single query. The query planner's output is as follows. Since I am newbie, I'm not yet able to understand the way Mongo indices work.

```
{
"queryPlanner" : {
    "plannerVersion" : 1,
    "namespace" : "wizn_iot.nodeData",
    "indexFilterSet" : false,
    "parsedQuery" : {
        "$and" : [
            {
                "$or" : [
                    {
                        "$and" : [
                            {
                                "hubId" : {
                                    "$eq" : "87-0c-4e-a6-ff-39-cc-94"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "nodeId" : {
                                    "$eq" : 1
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "neid" : {
                            "$eq" : "40-cb-28-dd-46-e7-d9-c3"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "capturedAt" : {
                    "$lte" : ISODate("2017-11-19T05:17:30Z")
                }
            },
            {
                "capturedAt" : {
                    "$gt" : ISODate("2017-11-12T05:17:30Z")
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "winningPlan" : {
        "stage" : "KEEP_MUTATIONS",
        "inputStage" : {
            "stage" : "FETCH",
            "filter" : {
                "$and" : [
                    {
                        "capturedAt" : {
                            "$lte" : ISODate("2017-11-19T05:17:30Z")
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "capturedAt" : {
                            "$gt" : ISODate("2017-11-12T05:17:30Z")
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "OR",
                "inputStages" : [
                    {
                        "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                        "keyPattern" : {
                            "hubId" : 1,
                            "nodeId" : 1
                        },
                        "indexName" : "hubId_1_nodeId_1",
                        "isMultiKey" : false,
                        "isUnique" : false,
                        "isSparse" : false,
                        "isPartial" : false,
                        "indexVersion" : 1,
                        "direction" : "forward",
                        "indexBounds" : {
                            "hubId" : [
                                "[\"87-0c-4e-a6-ff-39-cc-94\", \"87-0c-4e-a6-ff-39-cc-94\"]"
                            ],
                            "nodeId" : [
                                "[1.0, 1.0]"
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                        "keyPattern" : {
                            "neid" : 1,
                            "hubId" : 1,
                            "nodeId" : 1,
                            "capturedAt" : 1
                        },
                        "indexName" : "neid_1_hubId_1_nodeId_1_capturedAt_1",
                        "isMultiKey" : false,
                        "isUnique" : false,
                        "isSparse" : false,
                        "isPartial" : false,
                        "indexVersion" : 1,
                        "direction" : "forward",
                        "indexBounds" : {
                            "neid" : [
                                "[\"40-cb-28-dd-46-e7-d9-c3\", \"40-cb-28-dd-46-e7-d9-c3\"]"
                            ],
                            "hubId" : [
                                "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                            ],
                            "nodeId" : [
                                "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                            ],
                            "capturedAt" : [
                                "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    "rejectedPlans" : [
        {
            "stage" : "KEEP_MUTATIONS",
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "FETCH",
                "filter" : {
                    "$and" : [
                        {
                            "capturedAt" : {
                                "$lte" : ISODate("2017-11-19T05:17:30Z")
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "capturedAt" : {
                                "$gt" : ISODate("2017-11-12T05:17:30Z")
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "inputStage" : {
                    "stage" : "OR",
                    "inputStages" : [
                        {
                            "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                            "keyPattern" : {
                                "hubId" : 1,
                                "nodeId" : 1,
                                "capturedAt" : 1
                            },
                            "indexName" : "hubId_1_nodeId_1_capturedAt_1",
                            "isMultiKey" : false,
                            "isUnique" : false,
                            "isSparse" : false,
                            "isPartial" : false,
                            "indexVersion" : 1,
                            "direction" : "forward",
                            "indexBounds" : {
                                "hubId" : [
                                    "[\"87-0c-4e-a6-ff-39-cc-94\", \"87-0c-4e-a6-ff-39-cc-94\"]"
                                ],
                                "nodeId" : [
                                    "[1.0, 1.0]"
                                ],
                                "capturedAt" : [
                                    "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                                ]
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                            "keyPattern" : {
                                "neid" : 1,
                                "hubId" : 1,
                                "nodeId" : 1,
                                "capturedAt" : 1
                            },
                            "indexName" : "neid_1_hubId_1_nodeId_1_capturedAt_1",
                            "isMultiKey" : false,
                            "isUnique" : false,
                            "isSparse" : false,
                            "isPartial" : false,
                            "indexVersion" : 1,
                            "direction" : "forward",
                            "indexBounds" : {
                                "neid" : [
                                    "[\"40-cb-28-dd-46-e7-d9-c3\", \"40-cb-28-dd-46-e7-d9-c3\"]"
                                ],
                                "hubId" : [
                                    "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                                ],
                                "nodeId" : [
                                    "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                                ],
                                "capturedAt" : [
                                    "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "stage" : "KEEP_MUTATIONS",
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "FETCH",
                "filter" : {
                    "$and" : [
                        {
                            "capturedAt" : {
                                "$lte" : ISODate("2017-11-19T05:17:30Z")
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "capturedAt" : {
                                "$gt" : ISODate("2017-11-12T05:17:30Z")
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "inputStage" : {
                    "stage" : "OR",
                    "inputStages" : [
                        {
                            "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                            "keyPattern" : {
                                "hubId" : 1,
                                "nodeId" : 1,
                                "neid" : 1,
                                "capturedAt" : 1
                            },
                            "indexName" : "hubId_1_nodeId_1_neid_1_capturedAt_1",
                            "isMultiKey" : false,
                            "isUnique" : false,
                            "isSparse" : false,
                            "isPartial" : false,
                            "indexVersion" : 1,
                            "direction" : "forward",
                            "indexBounds" : {
                                "hubId" : [
                                    "[\"87-0c-4e-a6-ff-39-cc-94\", \"87-0c-4e-a6-ff-39-cc-94\"]"
                                ],
                                "nodeId" : [
                                    "[1.0, 1.0]"
                                ],
                                "neid" : [
                                    "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                                ],
                                "capturedAt" : [
                                    "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                                ]
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                            "keyPattern" : {
                                "neid" : 1,
                                "hubId" : 1,
                                "nodeId" : 1,
                                "capturedAt" : 1
                            },
                            "indexName" : "neid_1_hubId_1_nodeId_1_capturedAt_1",
                            "isMultiKey" : false,
                            "isUnique" : false,
                            "isSparse" : false,
                            "isPartial" : false,
                            "indexVersion" : 1,
                            "direction" : "forward",
                            "indexBounds" : {
                                "neid" : [
                                    "[\"40-cb-28-dd-46-e7-d9-c3\", \"40-cb-28-dd-46-e7-d9-c3\"]"
                                ],
                                "hubId" : [
                                    "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                                ],
                                "nodeId" : [
                                    "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                                ],
                                "capturedAt" : [
                                    "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "stage" : "KEEP_MUTATIONS",
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "FETCH",
                "filter" : {
                    "$and" : [
                        {
                            "capturedAt" : {
                                "$lte" : ISODate("2017-11-19T05:17:30Z")
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "capturedAt" : {
                                "$gt" : ISODate("2017-11-12T05:17:30Z")
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "inputStage" : {
                    "stage" : "OR",
                    "inputStages" : [
                        {
                            "stage" : "FETCH",
                            "filter" : {
                                "nodeId" : {
                                    "$eq" : 1
                                }
                            },
                            "inputStage" : {
                                "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                                "keyPattern" : {
                                    "hubId" : 1
                                },
                                "indexName" : "hubId_1",
                                "isMultiKey" : false,
                                "isUnique" : false,
                                "isSparse" : false,
                                "isPartial" : false,
                                "indexVersion" : 1,
                                "direction" : "forward",
                                "indexBounds" : {
                                    "hubId" : [
                                        "[\"87-0c-4e-a6-ff-39-cc-94\", \"87-0c-4e-a6-ff-39-cc-94\"]"
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                            "keyPattern" : {
                                "neid" : 1,
                                "hubId" : 1,
                                "nodeId" : 1,
                                "capturedAt" : 1
                            },
                            "indexName" : "neid_1_hubId_1_nodeId_1_capturedAt_1",
                            "isMultiKey" : false,
                            "isUnique" : false,
                            "isSparse" : false,
                            "isPartial" : false,
                            "indexVersion" : 1,
                            "direction" : "forward",
                            "indexBounds" : {
                                "neid" : [
                                    "[\"40-cb-28-dd-46-e7-d9-c3\", \"40-cb-28-dd-46-e7-d9-c3\"]"
                                ],
                                "hubId" : [
                                    "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                                ],
                                "nodeId" : [
                                    "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                                ],
                                "capturedAt" : [
                                    "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "stage" : "KEEP_MUTATIONS",
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "FETCH",
                "filter" : {
                    "$and" : [
                        {
                            "capturedAt" : {
                                "$lte" : ISODate("2017-11-19T05:17:30Z")
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "capturedAt" : {
                                "$gt" : ISODate("2017-11-12T05:17:30Z")
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "inputStage" : {
                    "stage" : "OR",
                    "inputStages" : [
                        {
                            "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                            "keyPattern" : {
                                "hubId" : 1,
                                "nodeId" : 1,
                                "capturedAt" : 1
                            },
                            "indexName" : "hubId_1_nodeId_1_capturedAt_1",
                            "isMultiKey" : false,
                            "isUnique" : false,
                            "isSparse" : false,
                            "isPartial" : false,
                            "indexVersion" : 1,
                            "direction" : "forward",
                            "indexBounds" : {
                                "hubId" : [
                                    "[\"87-0c-4e-a6-ff-39-cc-94\", \"87-0c-4e-a6-ff-39-cc-94\"]"
                                ],
                                "nodeId" : [
                                    "[1.0, 1.0]"
                                ],
                                "capturedAt" : [
                                    "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                                ]
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                            "keyPattern" : {
                                "neid" : 1
                            },
                            "indexName" : "neid_1",
                            "isMultiKey" : false,
                            "isUnique" : false,
                            "isSparse" : false,
                            "isPartial" : false,
                            "indexVersion" : 1,
                            "direction" : "forward",
                            "indexBounds" : {
                                "neid" : [
                                    "[\"40-cb-28-dd-46-e7-d9-c3\", \"40-cb-28-dd-46-e7-d9-c3\"]"
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "stage" : "KEEP_MUTATIONS",
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "FETCH",
                "filter" : {
                    "$and" : [
                        {
                            "capturedAt" : {
                                "$lte" : ISODate("2017-11-19T05:17:30Z")
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "capturedAt" : {
                                "$gt" : ISODate("2017-11-12T05:17:30Z")
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "inputStage" : {
                    "stage" : "OR",
                    "inputStages" : [
                        {
                            "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                            "keyPattern" : {
                                "hubId" : 1,
                                "nodeId" : 1
                            },
                            "indexName" : "hubId_1_nodeId_1",
                            "isMultiKey" : false,
                            "isUnique" : false,
                            "isSparse" : false,
                            "isPartial" : false,
                            "indexVersion" : 1,
                            "direction" : "forward",
                            "indexBounds" : {
                                "hubId" : [
                                    "[\"87-0c-4e-a6-ff-39-cc-94\", \"87-0c-4e-a6-ff-39-cc-94\"]"
                                ],
                                "nodeId" : [
                                    "[1.0, 1.0]"
                                ]
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                            "keyPattern" : {
                                "neid" : 1
                            },
                            "indexName" : "neid_1",
                            "isMultiKey" : false,
                            "isUnique" : false,
                            "isSparse" : false,
                            "isPartial" : false,
                            "indexVersion" : 1,
                            "direction" : "forward",
                            "indexBounds" : {
                                "neid" : [
                                    "[\"40-cb-28-dd-46-e7-d9-c3\", \"40-cb-28-dd-46-e7-d9-c3\"]"
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "stage" : "KEEP_MUTATIONS",
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "FETCH",
                "filter" : {
                    "$and" : [
                        {
                            "capturedAt" : {
                                "$lte" : ISODate("2017-11-19T05:17:30Z")
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "capturedAt" : {
                                "$gt" : ISODate("2017-11-12T05:17:30Z")
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "inputStage" : {
                    "stage" : "OR",
                    "inputStages" : [
                        {
                            "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                            "keyPattern" : {
                                "hubId" : 1,
                                "nodeId" : 1,
                                "neid" : 1,
                                "capturedAt" : 1
                            },
                            "indexName" : "hubId_1_nodeId_1_neid_1_capturedAt_1",
                            "isMultiKey" : false,
                            "isUnique" : false,
                            "isSparse" : false,
                            "isPartial" : false,
                            "indexVersion" : 1,
                            "direction" : "forward",
                            "indexBounds" : {
                                "hubId" : [
                                    "[\"87-0c-4e-a6-ff-39-cc-94\", \"87-0c-4e-a6-ff-39-cc-94\"]"
                                ],
                                "nodeId" : [
                                    "[1.0, 1.0]"
                                ],
                                "neid" : [
                                    "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                                ],
                                "capturedAt" : [
                                    "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                                ]
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                            "keyPattern" : {
                                "neid" : 1
                            },
                            "indexName" : "neid_1",
                            "isMultiKey" : false,
                            "isUnique" : false,
                            "isSparse" : false,
                            "isPartial" : false,
                            "indexVersion" : 1,
                            "direction" : "forward",
                            "indexBounds" : {
                                "neid" : [
                                    "[\"40-cb-28-dd-46-e7-d9-c3\", \"40-cb-28-dd-46-e7-d9-c3\"]"
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "stage" : "KEEP_MUTATIONS",
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "FETCH",
                "filter" : {
                    "$and" : [
                        {
                            "capturedAt" : {
                                "$lte" : ISODate("2017-11-19T05:17:30Z")
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "capturedAt" : {
                                "$gt" : ISODate("2017-11-12T05:17:30Z")
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "inputStage" : {
                    "stage" : "OR",
                    "inputStages" : [
                        {
                            "stage" : "FETCH",
                            "filter" : {
                                "nodeId" : {
                                    "$eq" : 1
                                }
                            },
                            "inputStage" : {
                                "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                                "keyPattern" : {
                                    "hubId" : 1
                                },
                                "indexName" : "hubId_1",
                                "isMultiKey" : false,
                                "isUnique" : false,
                                "isSparse" : false,
                                "isPartial" : false,
                                "indexVersion" : 1,
                                "direction" : "forward",
                                "indexBounds" : {
                                    "hubId" : [
                                        "[\"87-0c-4e-a6-ff-39-cc-94\", \"87-0c-4e-a6-ff-39-cc-94\"]"
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                            "keyPattern" : {
                                "neid" : 1
                            },
                            "indexName" : "neid_1",
                            "isMultiKey" : false,
                            "isUnique" : false,
                            "isSparse" : false,
                            "isPartial" : false,
                            "indexVersion" : 1,
                            "direction" : "forward",
                            "indexBounds" : {
                                "neid" : [
                                    "[\"40-cb-28-dd-46-e7-d9-c3\", \"40-cb-28-dd-46-e7-d9-c3\"]"
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "stage" : "KEEP_MUTATIONS",
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "FETCH",
                "filter" : {
                    "$or" : [
                        {
                            "$and" : [
                                {
                                    "hubId" : {
                                        "$eq" : "87-0c-4e-a6-ff-39-cc-94"
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    "nodeId" : {
                                        "$eq" : 1
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "neid" : {
                                "$eq" : "40-cb-28-dd-46-e7-d9-c3"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "inputStage" : {
                    "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                    "keyPattern" : {
                        "capturedAt" : 1
                    },
                    "indexName" : "capturedAt_1",
                    "isMultiKey" : false,
                    "isUnique" : false,
                    "isSparse" : false,
                    "isPartial" : false,
                    "indexVersion" : 1,
                    "direction" : "forward",
                    "indexBounds" : {
                        "capturedAt" : [
                            "(new Date(1510463850000), new Date(1511068650000)]"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
},
"executionStats" : {
    "executionSuccess" : true,
    "nReturned" : 1408,
    "executionTimeMillis" : 28908,
    "totalKeysExamined" : 16478,
    "totalDocsExamined" : 16478,
    "executionStages" : {
        "stage" : "KEEP_MUTATIONS",
        "nReturned" : 1408,
        "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 2620,
        "works" : 16531,
        "advanced" : 1408,
        "needTime" : 15071,
        "needYield" : 51,
        "saveState" : 2114,
        "restoreState" : 2114,
        "isEOF" : 1,
        "invalidates" : 0,
        "inputStage" : {
            "stage" : "FETCH",
            "filter" : {
                "$and" : [
                    {
                        "capturedAt" : {
                            "$lte" : ISODate("2017-11-19T05:17:30Z")
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "capturedAt" : {
                            "$gt" : ISODate("2017-11-12T05:17:30Z")
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            "nReturned" : 1408,
            "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 2620,
            "works" : 16531,
            "advanced" : 1408,
            "needTime" : 15071,
            "needYield" : 51,
            "saveState" : 2114,
            "restoreState" : 2114,
            "isEOF" : 1,
            "invalidates" : 0,
            "docsExamined" : 16478,
            "alreadyHasObj" : 0,
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "OR",
                "nReturned" : 16478,
                "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 140,
                "works" : 16480,
                "advanced" : 16478,
                "needTime" : 1,
                "needYield" : 0,
                "saveState" : 2114,
                "restoreState" : 2114,
                "isEOF" : 1,
                "invalidates" : 0,
                "dupsTested" : 16478,
                "dupsDropped" : 0,
                "locsForgotten" : 0,
                "inputStages" : [
                    {
                        "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                        "nReturned" : 16478,
                        "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 30,
                        "works" : 16479,
                        "advanced" : 16478,
                        "needTime" : 0,
                        "needYield" : 0,
                        "saveState" : 2114,
                        "restoreState" : 2114,
                        "isEOF" : 1,
                        "invalidates" : 0,
                        "keyPattern" : {
                            "hubId" : 1,
                            "nodeId" : 1
                        },
                        "indexName" : "hubId_1_nodeId_1",
                        "isMultiKey" : false,
                        "isUnique" : false,
                        "isSparse" : false,
                        "isPartial" : false,
                        "indexVersion" : 1,
                        "direction" : "forward",
                        "indexBounds" : {
                            "hubId" : [
                                "[\"87-0c-4e-a6-ff-39-cc-94\", \"87-0c-4e-a6-ff-39-cc-94\"]"
                            ],
                            "nodeId" : [
                                "[1.0, 1.0]"
                            ]
                        },
                        "keysExamined" : 16478,
                        "dupsTested" : 0,
                        "dupsDropped" : 0,
                        "seenInvalidated" : 0
                    },
                    {
                        "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                        "nReturned" : 0,
                        "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 110,
                        "works" : 1,
                        "advanced" : 0,
                        "needTime" : 0,
                        "needYield" : 0,
                        "saveState" : 2114,
                        "restoreState" : 2114,
                        "isEOF" : 1,
                        "invalidates" : 0,
                        "keyPattern" : {
                            "neid" : 1,
                            "hubId" : 1,
                            "nodeId" : 1,
                            "capturedAt" : 1
                        },
                        "indexName" : "neid_1_hubId_1_nodeId_1_capturedAt_1",
                        "isMultiKey" : false,
                        "isUnique" : false,
                        "isSparse" : false,
                        "isPartial" : false,
                        "indexVersion" : 1,
                        "direction" : "forward",
                        "indexBounds" : {
                            "neid" : [
                                "[\"40-cb-28-dd-46-e7-d9-c3\", \"40-cb-28-dd-46-e7-d9-c3\"]"
                            ],
                            "hubId" : [
                                "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                            ],
                            "nodeId" : [
                                "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                            ],
                            "capturedAt" : [
                                "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                            ]
                        },
                        "keysExamined" : 0,
                        "dupsTested" : 0,
                        "dupsDropped" : 0,
                        "seenInvalidated" : 0
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
},
"serverInfo" : {
    "host" : "prod-clone",
    "port" : 27017,
    "version" : "3.2.4",
    "gitVersion" : "e2ee9ffcf9f5a94fad76802e28cc978718bb7a30"
},
"ok" : 1
}
```

Each stage's execution time is in milli seconds where as the overall execution time is around 29s ("executionTimeMillis" : 28908) . Which is the bottleneck here and how can I optimize my indices?

Comment: how much memory/cpu you have on this server? how many queries are sent per sec? What version of mongodb it is?

Comment: Mongo version 3.2.4. I'm running it on Google Compute instance with 1vcpu and 6.5gb RAM. Plenty of RAM is free. CPU becomes the bottle neck. Its very unclear about which stage is the bottleneck here and I am unable to optimize without understanding it.